# Residue of $\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{z-1})}{z^2 \sin z}$ at $z=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Residue of $$\frac{1}{z^2 \sin z}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{z-1}\right)$$ at $z=1$.

More importantly, I don't even know whether it exists or not. The one who creates this question has made questions that are unsolvable.

I have tried some methods while they are not so successful.

1. Wolfram alpha. It doesn't even give an answer this times.
2. Series expansion. But this turns out to be too ugly. Expanding $\cos$, $z^2$ and $\sin $ respectively, and evaluate the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z-1}$ seems impossible and silly (without aid of matlab).
3. see if it is a removable singularity. Considering $\lim_{z \to 1} (z-1) f(z)$, I once thought I made it by $-1 \leq \cos z \leq 1$, but this inequality doesn't apply in complex.

Please help.

Comment: It's an isolated singularity, so the residue exists. It is an essential singularity, so you basically have to do the series expansions, unless you somehow find a short-cut. I'm afraid it **will** be ugly.

Comment: @DanielFischer: it is not so ugly. Since the cosine is an even function, the residue is just zero.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Are you forgetting the contributions of $\frac{1}{z^2\sin z}$? I don't see how they will cancel.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ok, you are right, my fault.

Comment: It seems very difficult to get an explicit value for this. The singularity is essential and the series expansion of $1/z^2 \sin z$ is terrible. A numerical approximation of the residue is $-4.714388$ for what it's worth.

Comment: I think I got the point. It is really hard to compute the residue in the essential singularity, but it is rather easy to compute the residues in any other singularity. Since the sum of all the residues must be zero, the residue in the essential singularity can be written as a convergent series.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio $\mathbb{C}$ is not a compact Riemann surface, the sum of the residues need not be $0$ (consider $\cot z$). And $\infty$ is not an isolated singularity, so you can't use the result for $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: however, numerical evidence agree with the fact that the residue in $z=1$ is just the opposite of the sum of the residues for $z\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio And in this case, the numerical evidence is not lying. However, you need a correct argument why your idea (a good one, by the way) works. "The sum of the residues is $0$" is not a correct argument, since that generally isn't the case when we have non-isolated singularities. How can you show that the sum of all residues is indeed $0$?

Comment: @DanielFischer: He needs to find an integration contour encompassing all of the poles such that the integral of this function over that contour is zero.  The fact that his series agrees with the evidence suggests that such a contour exists.  But until he finds one, then he has not really solved the problem.

Comment: @DanielFischer: actually, now that I think of it, it isn't that hard.  Just take the circle of radius $R$ centered at the origin, take $R \to \infty$, and you are done because the integral is clearly bounded by zero as $O(1/R)$.

Comment: @RonGordon Not quite that, we must take particular values of $R$ only, so that $\sin z$ stays away from $0$ on $\lvert z\rvert = R_k$. $R_k = (k+1/2)\pi$ for example.

Comment: @DanielFischer: yes, good point, but I don't think that is a fatal hurdle.

Comment: @RonGordon No, not fatal at all. One just has to take a little care to avoid the dogpiles on the pavement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of computing the residue in the given point, compute the residues in the other singularities. Given $f(z)=\frac{\cos\frac{\pi}{z-1}}{z^2\sin z},$ we have:

$$ \operatorname{Res}_{z=k\pi} f(z) = \frac{(-1)^k}{\pi^2 k^2} \cos\frac{\pi}{\pi k -1} $$
for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus 0$ and:

$$ \operatorname{Res}_{z=0} f(z) = \frac{3\pi^2-1}{6},$$
so the residue you want to compute is given by a convergent series:
$$ \operatorname{Res}_{z=1} f(z) = \frac{1-3\pi^2}{6}-\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{\pi^2 k^2}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{\pi k-1}+\cos\frac{\pi}{\pi k+1}\right) = \color{red}{-4.7143885\ldots}.$$

Thanks to Daniel Fischer and Ron Gordon, this holds because the sum of all the residues is zero, since for any positive number $n$,
$$ \oint_{|z|=\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi}f(z)\,dz = O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$
Moreover, since for any positive natural number $k$:
$$ \operatorname{Res}_{z=k\pi}f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\left(\int_{|z|=(k+1/2)\pi}f(z)\,dz-\int_{|z|=(k-1/2)\pi}f(z)\,dz\right) = O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right), $$
we have:
$$ \oint_{|z|=R}f(z)\,dz=O\left(\frac{1}{R}\right) $$
for any $R\in\mathbb{R}_{>1}\setminus\pi\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: @DanielFischer: I've just completely re-written my answer.

Comment: The only way I can think of expressing a residue at one pole as a sum of the residues of all the others is by otherwise determining the integral the function over some contour $C$.  I don't see how you've done that.

Comment: As mentioned above, a good idea, but the argument for its correctness is necessary.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: all you need to do to complete this is consider the integral of the function over a circle of radius $R$ centered at the origin, and take $R \to \infty$.

Comment: @RonGordon: many thanks, answer just updated.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: thank you.  This was good, reminiscent of evaluating series using the residue theorem.